# getRootLogger() equivalent in JBoss Logging

Tags: jboss, log4j, jboss-eap-6, jboss-logging

I am migrating an application from Weblogic to JBoss EAP 6.4. The application originally used `Log4J` and an external logging configuration properties file. From what I understand, using `Log4J` would require the `log4j.xml` or `log4j.properties` file to be packaged inside the EAR and it would prevent us from changing the logging configuration at runtime.

Currently, I am ok with using the JBoss Logging subsystem to do the logging. However, the application has calls like:

```
Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
```

What is the equivalent in JBoss Logging, if I needed to get the `RootLogger`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use log4j essentially as a logging facade. In other words you don't need to change your logging code at all.

If you want to use the logging subsystem for configuration just ensure your deployment does not have a `log4j.xml` or `log4j.properties` file as you stated.

If you want to swap out log4j and use JBoss Logging the equivalent for `Logger.getRootLogger()` would just be `Logger.getLogger("")`.